# How to execute remote bat file using build step in TeamCity?

Tags: windows, batch-file, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have TeamCity installed on centos. I have only one Linux BuildAgent for now. My build configuration execute a maven script and using ant upload WAR artifact to Windows Server on FTP. After this step i have to execute BAT file on remote Windows Server. I read that i can do this using psexec/RemCom, but i can't understand how i can do this in TeamCity? Build Step or different Build Configuration should contain steps to execute psexec/RemCom or i can insert Build Step into existed Build Configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single build configuration could potentially consists of multiple [build steps](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Steps). Think of them as a actions you would like to do. So I suppose that right now you have a maven step in your build configuration. I would suggest you to add [Command Line](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Command+Line) step, where you can do what ever you want -- it's like bash/batch script. You can put script contents directly to the build step, or you can write script and execute it.
But as you mentioned that you have CentOS, it could be you have to do [extra configuration](http://steronius.blogspot.de/2013/05/psexec-via-linux.html) on the build agent for PsExec to be available.